# I need to place a block or image for bumdle product alone in magento?

Tags: magento-enterprise

I need to place a static block or image below the breadcrumbs in all bundle product pages.

How to achieve this.Help me with a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by placing a new structural block just below `breadcumb` block for `product view` page. To do this, just follow these steps

### 1. Define new structural block via layout XML

File : `app\design\frontend\<package>\<theme>\layout\local.xml`

```
<layout>
    <!-- this section defines new structural block -->
    <default>
        <block type="core/text_list" name="product.view.image.block" as="image_block_for_product_view" translate="label">
            <label>Image Block For Bundle Product</label>
        </block>
    </default>
    <!-- this section includes your image static block to new structural block-->
    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="product.view.image.block">
            <block type="core/template" name="bundle.special.image.container" as="image_sb_for_bundle_pro" template="staticblock/image.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

Here as you can see, we first defined new structural block with name `product.view.image.block` using the layout handle `default`. This will let you include this block almost every page in magento. Then we included the static block to this newly created structural block through the handle `catalog_product_view`. This will ensure the block `bundle.special.image.container` only included to our new structural block only when a product view page is processed.

### 2. Define Position Of Structural Block

Now it is the time to position our new structural block. Since we need to position our structural block just below breadcumb block, we need to specify it in `page layout` file. Page Layout file means all basic template files that comes under `page\` folder in your theme.

Basically in your case, you just need to include this structural block in the page layout file that is using for your product view page. It may `2 column right` or `2 column left` or `1 column` etc. But I recommend you to include the structural block in every file that comes under above folder in your theme. This will allow you to use this block in every page layout, in any page(in future).

So basically, open the page layout file that used in your product view page. You can see a code like this there.

```
       <div class="main">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>
            <div class="col-main">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Put our block just below breadcurmb block as like this

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('image_block_for_product_view') ?>
```

That will position our new structural block just below the breadcrumbs block

### 3. Define Template File

File : `app\design\frontend\<package>\<theme>\template\staticblock/image.phtml`

```
<?php
    //get current product
    $_product  = Mage::registry('currrent_product');

    //checks whether bundle produc

    if($_product->getTypeId() == 'bundle'):
?>
        <div><?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block', 'image.for.bundle.product')->setBlockId('static_block_id')->toHtml(); ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

So the block just check whether curent product type is bundle or not. If yes, it will show the static block that holds the image.

Note: Dont forget to change the static block id with your own static block id

Hope that will help you

Comment: actually did you try this ?